# Can the 'See All' option in document be hidden in SP Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, folder, hide

[image]I am just wondering, is there any way of hiding the 'See All' option in the documents folder?
I want only the admin to be able to see the option and not the Read Users.
I have checked the permissions and other options, and I can't find if it's possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the "See All" you are referring to? Please offer a screenshot about it.

Comment: @LisaChenMSFT i have just attached an image where it is located.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to.  You can find out if the current user is a site admin using REST then use CSS to hide the See All link.  I do not have an online farm to play with right now to get the CSS but here is the code I use for admin checking on the client.  Put it in a Content Editor Web Part on the list.

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("loadPage"); //ensure the core.js is loaded onto the page before executing

function loadPage() {
    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser/issiteadmin",
        type: "GET",
        datatype:"json",
        headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    });
    call.done(function(data) { 
        var isSiteAdmin = data.d.IsSiteAdmin;
        checkActiveUser(isSiteAdmin);
    });
}
function checkActiveUser(isAdmin) {
    if (!isAdmin)
        $("input[id$='id of control without GUID']").css('display', 'none');
        //or $("input[id$='id of control without GUID']").hide();
        //your css to hide the control here
}
```

This should work for you.  Let me know if it works, or if you have any questions.  Good luck!